# Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine) does not working

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to create a table at database automatically when I run 'docker compose up'.

However it seems like code does not proceed any further at Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine) and code does not work.

Below is a part of the log and the executed code when running docker compose up.

main.py

```
from .admin.utils import currentTime
from .env import DB_URL
from .database import init_db

print(f" ################ app.main Started At {currentTime()} ################# ")

@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    print('*'*3)
    await init_db()
    print('end'*3)
```

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from typing import Generator
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, Session
from .env import HOSTNAME, PORT, USERNAME, PASSWORD, CHARSET, DATABASE, DB_URL
import pymysql

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(DB_URL, echo=True)
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
conn = pymysql.connect(host=HOSTNAME, port=PORT, user=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD, db=DATABASE, charset=CHARSET)
SessionLocal = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False))
db_session = Session()
Base.query = SessionLocal.query_property()


async def init_db():
    print('&' * 3)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    print('%' * 3)
```

models.py

```
from pydantic import BaseConfig
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from app.database import Base


class Good(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'goods'

    un = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(100))
    price = Column(String(100))
    category = Column(String(100))
    dutyfree_company = Column(String(100))

    class Config:
        BaseConfig.arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        allow_population_by_field_name = True

    def __str__(self):
        return f'고유 번호: {self.un}, \n ' \
               f'이름: {self.name}, \n ' \
               f'가격: {self.price} \n ' \
               f'카테고리: {self.category}' \
               f'면세점 회사: {self.dutyfree_company}'
```

log

```
api   | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
api   | INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT DATABASE()
api   | INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[raw sql] {}
api   |  ################ app.main Started At 20:51:59 #################
api   | ***
api   | &&&
api   | 2023-12-05 11:51:59,021 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
api   | 2023-12-05 11:51:59,021 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
api   | 2023-12-05 11:51:59,024 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT @@sql_mode
api   | 2023-12-05 11:51:59,025 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
api   | INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT @@sql_mode
api   | INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[raw sql] {}
api   | 2023-12-05 11:51:59,026 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT @@lower_case_table_names
api   | 2023-12-05 11:51:59,026 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
api   | INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT @@lower_case_table_names
api   | INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[raw sql] {}
api   | 2023-12-05 11:51:59,028 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
api   | INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
api   | INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:COMMIT
api   | 2023-12-05 11:51:59,029 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
api   | INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

Comment: The code in models.py must be executed to register the models with the metadata object. You might need to import models in main.py